# Check Protocol Inheritance at Runtime

Tags: swift, reflection, swift-protocols

It's easy to check protocol conformance of a type at runtime:

```
guard type is Encodable.Type else { ... }
```

but this technique fails if `type` is not a `struct` or `class`, but instead a `protocol` that inherits from `Encodable`. Is there a way to make a similar check for protocols?

Comment: What are you using this for? Can you provide a context for the check?

Comment: For example, say I wanted to check whether a custom collection should be `Encodable`. With `protocol Animal: Codable` and `class Person: Animal`, I'd be able to verify that `Group<Person>` should be `Encodable`, but I would have no way of verifying that `Group<Animal>` should be, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tad hacky, but it will probably solve your problem:

Given these example types:

```
protocol Animal: Encodable {}

struct Person: Animal {}

protocol SomeOtherProtocol {}

struct Demon: SomeOtherProtocol {}
```

I'm simplifing the init logic for the example by assuming:

```
typealias Group = Array
let animals: Group<Animal> = [Person(), Person(), Person()]
let notAnimals: Group<SomeOtherProtocol> = [Demon(), Demon(), Demon()]
```

This should work for a custom collection class however... Continuing, define the following extension for your custom Collection

```
extension Group {
    func asEncodables() -> Group<Encodable>?{
        return self as? Group<Encodable>
    }

    var isElementEncodable: Bool {
        return self is Group<Encodable>
    }
}
```

You now have access to the following:

```
animals.asEncodables() //returns some
notAnimals.asEncodables() // returns none

animals.isElementEncodable //true
notAnimals.isElementEncodable //false
```

And so for your original question, you could make your check as follows:

```
guard notAnimals.isElementEncodable else { return }
```

Hope this helps you. Currently I know of no way to make the comparison with something similar to an `if X is Y` :/

Comment: Works perfectly for my use case of generic wrappers and containers, and pretty clean, too! Let's just hope nobody needs it for any other situation. :)